# Azure MVC 4 Website throws a 502 server errors and having images and css loading issues

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

I’m deploying a website in azure server (mvc 4 website) and I keep on getting 502 errors.
It’s happening mainly in IE but sometimes in Chrome as well.

Another problem is sometimes the images and css files aren’t getting loaded when the user isn’t login (Authenticate).

Sometimes (when this issue is occurring) if I go directly to the image URL I’m redirected to the login page.

This problem happens only in IE (I know it’s a server problem but still, that’s the case).
Needless to say that all of the actions ActionResult are `[AllowAnonymous]`

In web config I have tried the `authorization` tag with `allow users="?"`
And location tag with attribute `path="~/Images" system.web => authorization => allow users="*,?"`

In localhost I have given those folders `IUSER` permissions, that did the job.
Can’t seem to overcome this problem /:
Does anybody know what to do or way am I getting those errors?